# How to access DropDown interface?

Tags: c#, excel

When I add Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel reference to my project I cannot find the DropDown Interface which is described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.dropdown(v=office.14).aspx

Anyone knows how to access it?

I would like to add a dropdown list to a cell as described here:

http://july-code.blogspot.com/2008/03/add-drop-down-list-into-excel-file.html

I'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel version 14.0 with the runtime version 2.0.50727.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not part of the `Application` interface but instead is it's own interface.

Not sure what your code looks like but however you declare the excel com object; Use that name.

So the way you declare something along the lines of `x = new Excel.Application()` where Excel is your com object name, whatever that name is you use `ComName.DropDowns` it will not be in intellisence, but it is there after you declare it.

So if your using is like this:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Then you probably have something *LIKE*:

```
Excel.Application oXL;
```

to get the Application Interface so when you want the drop down call it as:

```
Excel.DropDowns oDropDowns;
```

So if your using is:

```
using xlComObject = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

then the drop downs would be:

```
xlComObject.DropDowns MyExcelDropDowns;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what's the difference between "xlComObject" and "Excel"? They both are aliases to the same namespace. Also, I don't see "DropDowns" the closest I have is "DropLines". Here is a screen shot: http://imgur.com/DNHGv8x

Comment: @chhenning Thats my point there is no differenct just use whatever your alias is then `.DropDowns` if you fully read my answer you will see i stated that it will not be listed in intellisence but if you just enter it anyways and continue with your code you will ***NOT*** get an error.

Comment: You don't need both the Excel and xlComObject lines, only use one i was just stating that whatere the alias is you want to use that and NOT the `Application` interface.